# Changed username to push with to atlassian stash - update-server-info?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I have checked-out a repo from Atlassian Stash. When pushing back, I need to use another user name. I run

```
git config remote.origin.url new_user@my.host.com:either/branch/or/path
```

to change the remote origin, but after entering "git push" I get the message "/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?"

I don´t think I can run commands on Stash. So how to re-enable pushing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have separate URLs for fetching (pulling) and pushing.

```
git remote origin --set-url http://fetchurl
git remote origin --set-url --push https://user@pushurl
```

The problem is you are trying to change the name of the remote which has other impacts (e.g. directories under `refs/remotes/`)